# Ajax вывод комментариев

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Столкнулся с проблемой вывода комментов в конкретной статье. Для вывода воспользовался вызовом функции Ajax с определенным интервалом. Но комментарии не выводятся. Есть интересное условие, что при обычном  запросе :

```
SELECT * FROM `comment` ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

они отрабатывают вполне себе нормально, но игнорируют к какой статье привязаны. А если выборка с уточнением, где они должны находиться :

```
SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `post_id` = :id ORDER BY `id`DESC
```

ничего не выводит. Не могу решить эту проблему. Прошу помощи. Если какие-то есть недочеты, готов учиться.

форма  secondBooks.php

```php
<div id="allMessages" class="allMessages">
  <?php
     //вывод комментариев

  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `post_id` = :id ORDER BY `id`DESC';

  $query = $connect->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute([$id]);

$comments = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$str = '';
foreach ($comments as $key) {

 $str .=  "<div class='alert text-dark alert-secondary mb-2'>
  <h4>$key->name</h4>
  <p>$key->mess</p>
  </div>";
}
echo $str;


    ?>


</div>
    <form name="Formcom" id="Formcom" action="" method='post'>
<input name="id" id="id" value="<?=$id?>" type="hidden">
           <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2" id="block"></div>
      <label for="floatingInput">Ваше имя</label>
      
    <input type="text" name="username"  id = "username" class="form-control">

    <label for="floatingInput">Сообщение</label>
    <textarea name="message"id = "message" class="form-control"></textarea>
       <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary col-md-2 mt-4 " id="but_comment" type="button">Отправить</button>
 
    </form>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>


$('#but_comment').click(function () {
var username = $ ('#username').val();
var message = $ ('#message').val();
var id = $ ('#id').val();

$.ajax({

  url:'../controllers/comments.php',
  type : 'POST',
  cahe : false ,
  data : {'username' : username,'message' : message,'id' : id,},
  dataType : 'html',


        success: function (data) {
         if (data=='Готово'){
          $('.results').html(data);
         $('#block').hide();

         alert('Комментарий отправлен!');

         document.Formcom.reset();

        }
         else{
         $('#block').show();
         $('#block').text(data);
        }
        }


});
});
;

setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '../controllers/outComm.php', 
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
   
       $(".allMessages").html(data);

    }
  });
}, 3000);



</script>
```

outComm.php

```php
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `post_id` = :id ORDER BY `id`DESC';
  $query = $connect->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute([$id]);
  $comments = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$str = '';
foreach ($comments as $key) {

 $str .=  "<div class='alert text-dark alert-secondary mb-2'>
  <h4>$key->name</h4>
  <p>$key->mess</p>
  </div>";
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: Для начала хорошо бы понять, возвращает ли указанный запрос необходимые данные, если выполнить его в самой СУБД?

Comment: @АлександрПертенава Вы имеете ввиду массив данных ,который в форыче перебираю? Если так,то да,я проверял отладочной функцией,все данные есть

Comment: ID сообщения доходит до обработчика? Передается корректное значение?

Comment: @АлександрПертенава да и запись в бд корректная,все работает как часы кроме вывода,хотя информация о сообщении в массиве вся есть

Comment: Вы говорите о том, что ```выборка с уточнением где они должны находиться...ничего не выводит```. Отсюда вывод, что проблема в запросе. Поэтому я спросил: Запрос с указанием ID работает корректно? Ваш ответ: Да, данные в $comments есть. Логическая несостыковка.

Comment: @АлександрПертенава я не так вас понял

Comment: @АлександрПертенава что проблема в запросе понятно,но не знаю почему. В том то и дело,что в массиве $comments информация есть,а вывода на экран нет . Это странно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134354/discussion-between---and-c).

Answer (score 1):

В Ajax запросе к контроллеру controllers/outComm.php передавайте id поста:

```
...
data: {id: id}
...
```

а в контроллере перед строкой `$query->execute([$id]);` принимайте его:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Таким образом перестает передаваться значение в Бд

Comment: наверное потому что надо использовать $query->execute([':id' => $id]);

Comment: Происходит тогда нагрузка на память,комп сразу же разогнался и сам проект дико тормозит)Передача есть,но вывода нет

Comment: попробуйте самостоятельно исправить проблему с запросом в secondBooks.php и обратите внимание что фетчите ассоциативный массив (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) а результаты используете как объект $key->name